# How to fix titlesec overriding contentsname

Tags: conditionals, titlesec

I'm using the `titlesec` package to change the format of titles from this:
[image]

To this:

[image]

The way I did this can be illustrated using this MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
% This is the code that changes the title
\usepackage[explicit, compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\bfseries\huge}{\filright\huge}{0ex}
    {\huge\filright Module \thechapter: #1}
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{The Basics}

\end{document}
```

However, when I use this code to change the formatting of chapters, the title of the table of contents gets changed:
[image]

Where it should instead just say "Contents." How can I fix this? I've tried using the if else statement:

```
\usepackage[explicit, compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\bfseries\huge}{\filright\huge}{0ex}
    {\ifx\equal{#1}{\huge\filright \contentsname} \contentsname \else \huge\filright Module \thechapter: #1 \fi}
```

But that didn't change anything.

Comment: `\tableofconents` uses `\chapter*` (`\@makeschapterhead` as opposed to `\@makechapterhead`).  Unfortuneately, titlesec modifies both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delay to after `\tableofcontents`.

```
\documentclass{report}
% This is the code that changes the title
\usepackage[explicit, compact]{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\bfseries\huge}{\filright\huge}{0ex}
    {\huge\filright Module \thechapter: #1}

\chapter{The Basics}

\end{document}
```

[image: TOC]

Comment: Thank you, I'll implement this solution! Any idea why the if statement didn't work, though?

Comment: @Mailbox This is a bit of a hack, really, so you should probably accept Werner's answer.

Comment: The `\ifx\equal{#1}` compares token `\equal` with token `{`.  Hence it chooses the `\else` branch.  Here there is no `\else` branch.  I agree with @AlanMunn that Werner's answer is more complete than mine...

Answer (score 6):

Since `\tableofcontents` issues a `\chapter*` - a numberless chapter - you can specify a `numberless` `\titleformat`, where you remove all the content related to the numbering (like the `Module \thechapter:` prefix).

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

% This is the code that changes the title
\usepackage[explicit, compact]{titlesec}

\titleformat{name = \chapter}[display]
    {\bfseries\huge}{\filright\huge}{0ex}
    {\huge\filright Module \thechapter: #1}

\titleformat{name = \chapter, numberless}[display]
    {\bfseries\huge}{\filright\huge}{0ex}
    {#1}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{The Basics}

\end{document}
```